# Issue extracing specific XML values via BS4 and write them into dataframe

Tags: python, xml, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Python and trying my best to scrape some XML-data.
So far I got it to work for "normal" xPaths and attributes using `find` and `get` method, but I'm struggling with the last bit.

This is a sample section of the XML:

```
<root>
<job>
<othernodes>text</othernodes>
<advertiser>INPUT I WANT
    <node2>text</node2>
    <node3>text</node3>
</advertiser>
<othernodes>text</othernodes>
</job>
```

And this is part of my script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "sample url"

xml_data = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_data, "xml")

#Find the tag/child
child = soup.find("job")

Company = []

while True:
        try:
            Company.append(" ".join(child.find('advertiser')))
        except:
            Company.append(" ")
        try:
            # Next sibling of child, here: job
            child = child.find_next_sibling('job')
        except:
            break


data = []
data = pd.DataFrame({
    "advertiser":Company,
                        })
```

If I print the outcome it returns no values for the node advertiser.
I tried working around this  but can't find the solution.
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it could be cleaner if you use XPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use `ElementTree`, it's possible with `BeautifulSoup`.

Try calling the [`.find_next()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) method which returns the first match:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = """<root>
<job>
<othernodes>text</othernodes>
<advertiser>INPUT I WANT
    <node2>text</node2>
    <node3>text</node3>
</advertiser>
<othernodes>text</othernodes>
</job>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "html.parser")

print([soup.find("advertiser").find_next(text=True).strip()])

# Or using `find_all()`
# print([tag.find_next(text=True).strip() for tag in soup.find_all("advertiser")])
```

Output:

```
['INPUT I WANT']
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code you need

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

XML = '''<root>
    <job>
    <othernodes>text</othernodes>
    <advertiser>add1
        <node2>text</node2>
        <node3>text</node3>
    </advertiser>
    <othernodes>text</othernodes>
    </job>
    <job>
    <othernodes>text</othernodes>
    <advertiser>add2
        <node2>text</node2>
        <node3>text</node3>
    </advertiser>
    <othernodes>text</othernodes>
    </job>
</root>'''
root = ET.fromstring(XML)
data = [a.text.strip() for a in root.findall('.//advertiser')]
print(data)
```

output

```
['add1', 'add2']
```